# codeigniter load view within view by calling it from another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

This question seems the same to the others but it's actually different.

The situation is like this:
I have 2 controllers namely controller_1 and controller_2.
I have several views but for the purpose of this situation, I'll be giving view_1 and view_2.

Upon calling the index of controller_2, it will render a menu in view_2. In this menu, one particular link was supposed to load view_1 within a `div` of view_2.

The thing is, I've already created a function in controller_1 that will load view_1 with all the data needed from the model. Of course I can load the model again in controller_2, but the thing is, I will be repeating my codes found in one function of the controller_1. Btw, controller_1 behaves like a crud while controller_2 is like a controller for a module where it involves menus for several crud.

So how do I do it? How do I call view_1 within view_2 via calling controller_1 to load view_1 and insert it in view_2 using controller_2?

EDIT: if you're familiar with Tiles of struts (the old version), that's the similar thing I'm trying to accomplish here.

Comment: what exactly is your question? Do you want to access a controller's method from another controller?

Comment: @Robert sorry i forgot my question. I've edited it already.

Comment: How about placing the code preparing for view_2 in a helper or library which you can then load into both controller_1 and controller_2?

Comment: You normally don't do that in MVC structure. Perhaps this isn't the answer you're looking for, but take a look at how you structure your application, because you normally shouldn't need to do that. Try placing the content somewhere else and loading it from that into both controllers. If you really really need to, you can use AJAX for loading data from another controller.

Comment: @danneth @ Robert Thanks guys. That gives me a good idea of what to do. I think I'll be making a custom helper and load it into controller_2. In that way, I can use ajax to call this function which will only involve one controller.

Comment: The ajax part is for calling a controller site.com/controller. If you can use a helper method, thats much better because once loaded, you can just call myhelpermethod().

Answer (score 0):

I think if you simply use redirect from the method of Controller_2:

```
  Controller_2{
     function_to_call_a_method_from_controller_1{

        // You have to call the method of Controller 1
        return redirect('controller_1/function_of_controller_1_to_load_view');
     }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Code Igniter, when you need to use the same logic in more than one place, normally you create a [helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html) or a [library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html).